# touchesBegan method not getting invoked on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView embedded on top of a normal view. The view controllers touches began method is not getting invoked when I click on the collection view. At the same time it is getting invoked when I click upon an empty area. Any ideas?

Comment: UICollectionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // Set it in View Didload

Comment: But I do need collectionView's userinteraction set to yes. Is it possible to get both?

Comment: you can set userInteractionEnabled=YES on CollectionView and   userInteractionEnabled=NO  on collectionView Cell

Comment: set the cell's userInteraction to no is also making the collection view not respond.

Comment: I want my collectionview to respond and at the same time need a way to detect the user's touch point on screen.

Comment: manually Enable or disable userInteraction when you want or  when you dont .

Comment: Actually I want this to happen on longpress, and the collectionViewCell's on just tapping